# Why was this answer an audit, and why did I fail?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

A review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6557682 for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545272/find-the-number-of-increasing-sequence-of-length-k/27587290#27587290 just came up as an audit, and I failed it.

The audit text says,

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

I think we may have been looking at different answers. Based on the revision history, I see:

> If you want to check the number of increasing sequence of length k in the whole array :
>   You can pre-calculate the increasing sequence and then just check every index whether it can give an increasing sequence. Here is a sample code :

followed by a code block.

What does Stack Overflow see that I don't?

Answer (score 41):

Someone flagged it as spam for I have no freaking clue why. When the owner deleted it, the spam flag got marked as helpful, and the post became eligible as a review audit choice.

I've clear the spam flag off and re-deleted the answer. Should not cause problems in the future.

Comment: I wonder why I failed.

Comment: @John Because the system picks deleted posts with "helpful" spam flags on it as proven-bad audits, and it expected you to delete it. This post matched that criteria, but shouldn't have. Now that the spam flag has been changed to disputed, it can't be picked anymore.

Comment: My guess as to the audit is that someone was interpreting 'spam' not as advertisement but rather 'multiple reposts of the same material' as indicated in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545272/find-the-number-of-increasing-sequence-of-length-k#comment43598755_27545272).  If there is any deleted versions of the question, there is also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27473152/289086) version still undeleted that is the same question... reposted. You are correct that isn't why it should be flagged as spam, but thats also likely why the question was flagged.

Comment: Why is that answer deleted?

Comment: @lpapp Because the OP deleted it. I have to undelete it in order to clear the spam flags, so I re-deleted it as per their original wishes.

Comment: @animuson I feel I might have another answer in this vein, which caused me to fail an audit (please correct me if I'm wrong though): http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8469238. From the comments it seems this answer was *much* worse earlier on and so was probably flagged then, but now, while not a great answer, really has nothing much wrong with it. (An answer to the question it is on is quite similar and yet has +2 votes.)