# Why is there no option to close as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

The flag question dialog has an option to mark it as spam. The close dialog, on the other hand, does not have this option. Why is this so?

Comment: What do you consider spam to be?

Comment: "This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional." - This works for me.

Comment: Just making sure.  There are others who have flagged as spam because the person posts the same question multiple times (rather than closing as dup).  [This has caused problems in the past](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280999/why-was-this-answer-an-audit-and-why-did-i-fail/281000#comment133133_281000).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you close a question, you are giving the author a chance to improve his/her question and simply preventing answers from being added until the point where it is suitable for reopening.

The Stack Exchange definition of spam is as follows:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

That is not the kind of thing you want lying around. It doesn't make sense to close something as spam because spam cannot be improved; it inherently is useless and should be removed as soon as possible.

As such, you can only flag something as spam, which will bring it to a moderator's attention for immediate deletion. ([Or, if enough (6) flags accrue before this, it will be auto-deleted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281454/why-is-there-no-option-to-close-as-spam/281456?noredirect=1#comment135651_281456))

Comment: Yup; also, though: six spam flags also deletes, without a moderator. (Not really directly related, but...!)

Comment: Thanks @AstroCB. Your explanation really drives the point home about the intent of flagging and closing.